# python program not giving desired result

Tags: python

```
def main():
    names=[0]*10
    for index in range(len(names)):
        names[index] = input("Enter word " + str(index + 1) + ": ")
    bubbleSort(names)
    print("Names in Alphabetical order:")
    print(names)
def bubbleSort(names):
    for maxElement in range(len(names)-1, 0, -1):
        for index in range(maxElement):
            if names[index] > names[index+1]:
                temp = names[index]
                names[index] = names[index+1]
                names[index+1] = temp
    found = False
    index=0
    while found == False and index < len(names):
       Searchword= input('enter a searchword:')
       if scores[index] == Searchword :
            found = True
        else:
            index = index + 1
    if found:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")

main()
```

Does everything required accept when a Searchword is entered that cannot be found it does not print 'not found' but only keeps asking for input.

Comment: It's easier to solve problems like these if you can identify a specific problem with the code. What's the desired result, and which specific part of the code are you working on now? (See http://sscce.org/: it offers some helpful advice for scenarios like this one.)

Comment: It is supposed to say found if the Searchword is found in the array(which it does),but it does not say not found if it is not.It just keeps asking for input.

Comment: What is `scores`?  As in `if scores[index] == Searchword`.  `scores` isn't defined in any of the code you've shown.

Comment: Sorry Typo, it is meant to say 'names'. Sorry about that.

Comment: global name 'scores' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change `if scores[index] == Searchword` : to `if names[index] == Searchword :`
2. Place `Searchword= input('enter a searchword:')` outside the `while` loop

It should look something like this:

```
def main():
    names=[0]*10
    for index in range(len(names)):
        names[index] = input("Enter word " + str(index + 1) + ": ")
    bubbleSort(names)
    print("Names in Alphabetical order:")
    print(names)
def bubbleSort(names):
    for maxElement in range(len(names)-1, 0, -1):
        for index in range(maxElement):
            if names[index] > names[index+1]:
                temp = names[index]
                names[index] = names[index+1]
                names[index+1] = temp
    found = False
    index=0
    Searchword= input('enter a searchword:')
    while found == False and index < len(names):
       if names[index] == Searchword :
            found = True
        else:
            index = index + 1
    if found:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

you might need input before the loop, ie:

```
Searchword= input('enter a searchword:')    
while found == False and index < len(names):       
   if scores[index] == Searchword :
        found = True
    else:
        index = index + 1
```